# InputMethodService lifecycle bug

Tags: android, android-input-method

I am writing my own `InputMethodService` and I want to detect basically when the keyboard pops up and down in order to start and stop doing stuff. I have the simplest `MyInput' class that does very little:

```
public class MyInput extends InputMethodService {
    private static final String TAG = "MyInput";

    @Override
    public View onCreateInputView() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreateInputView");
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_keyboard, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartInput(EditorInfo attribute, boolean restarting) {
        super.onStartInput(EditorInfo attribute, boolean restarting);
        Log.d(TAG, "onStartInput restarting = " + restarting);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinishInput() {
        super.onFinishInput();
        Log.d(TAG, "onFinishInput");
    }
}
```

My view pops up and down normally but in the log, I can see a very strange behavior. Every time the keyboard shows or hide, both functions are called; making it impossible for me to detect when it's actually showing or not.

```
/** Keyboard not showing, I press an TextView **/
D  onFinishInput
D  onStartInput restarting = false
/** Keyboard showing, I press back **/
D  onFinishInput
D  onStartInput restarting = false
/** Keyboard not showing **/
```

I don't understand why such a simple example doesn't work. Thanks for any help

Comment: Hmm reading the Android APIs description for InputMethodService it mentions that "When the user switches between input targets, you will receive calls to onFinishInput() and onStartInput(EditorInfo, boolean)". This would explain the behaviour you are experiencing.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/InputMethodService.html

Comment: Agreed, I think the documentation is really lacking/not telling the truth for this class. I ended up using onWindowShown and onWindowHidden to detect when the keyboard is showing or not

Comment: The key thing to understand is that all key input goes through the InputMethodService, whether the window is visible or not. When the activity is first shown, it makes an InputConnection that handles basic things like the volume keys, the back key, dpad navigation (if the device has a dpad), etc. When the user focuses an EditText, you get an OnFinishInput for the basic InputConnection, and then an onStartInput for the EditText's InputConnection. You can generally distinguish these two cases by checking whether EditorInfo.inputType == InputType.TYPE_NULL.

Answer (score 4):

The [official documentation of the IME Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/creating-input-method#InputMethodLifecycle) is really lacking unfortunately. Through lots of debugging I created (for myself initially) a much better documentation of the IME Lifecycle:

[image: IME Lifecycle]

Regarding your initial question, if you want to know if your Keyboard is currently showing or not you shouldn't look at `onStartInput`, but you need to look at `onStartInputView`. Your Keyboard is visible in the calls between `onStartInputView` and `onFinishInputView`.